# Number of Occurrences above a certain number SQL

Tags: sql, project, sqlfire

I need to find how many times each value occurs, although I need to only display the values that occur 4 or more times. I know how to find the number of times a value occurs, but I don't know the second half. Here is an example of my data.

```
id | Order id
--------------
191 | 1020
150 | 1090
191 | 1023
140 | 1033
191 | 2132
191 | 1233
191 | 1321
```

I want to output something like this

```
ID  | Occurrences 
---------------
191 |  5
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Please don't change the question, especially when it's already been answered and answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id , COUNT(Order id) FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(Order id) > 4
```

Comment: edit the same question i will post the answer or you can post new question